# Can't log in to back end

Tags: maintenance-mode

I have been trying to upgrade to 8.8.3 from 8.4.4 for some time. My 8.4.4 site was holding but after repairing a database malfulnction in which the watchdog file went mad with assert errors, now I can't login to the back end. After failing to login using the login module on the front page, the WSOD appears with this meesage.

'''The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Missing required keys (core) in core/modules/path_alias/path_alias.info.yml in Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserDynamic->parse() (line 29 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoParserDynamic.php).'''

I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: Do you have try to clear browser cache and cookies?

Comment: I test in three browsers, Chrome and Firefox on Windows and Safari on the Mac. And I try to empty the caches.

Comment: Have you run the database update script?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the new `core_version_requirement` key taking the place of the `core` key in **module.info** files. Here's the change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/3070687.

A dirty hack to get around this would be to add the following to **path_alias**'s .info file:

- `core: 8.x`

I would do this only for the purpose of getting your site back in order, and remove the key afterwards. You are likely to run into this error, or similar, for other modules as well. I think that disabling the **path_alias** module, and any other troublesome modules, prior to upgrade might help.

This change record about **path_alias** becoming its own core module might be relevant, as well: https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086.

It's also worth mentioning that, if you have [drush](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) installed, you can get a one-time login link by running `drush uli 1`. You'll get a link that looks something like this: http://default/user/reset/1/1584508997/mFfBCIO2zmwKOm3Bh7l5bBwGxwMO6MVqJ6-S-cvZ-pU/login. Take the part of the URL starting with "/user" and append it to your domain name.

Ex: http://my.site.dev/user/reset/1/1584508997/mFfBCIO2zmwKOm3Bh7l5bBwGxwMO6MVqJ6-S-cvZ-pU/login